# Список захвата в лямбда-функциях: есть ли смысл захватывать все переменные?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Внутри квадратных скобок в определении лямбда-функции можно задать переменные из внешнего контекста, которые нужны для работы этой лямбда функции. Можно их перечислить вручную, а можно просто задать захват всех переменных сразу:

```
auto lambda1 = [x](int a) {return a < x; }; // Список захвата задан вручную
auto lambda2 = [&](int a) {return a < x; }; // Тупо захватываем всё по ссылке
```

Собственно вопрос: при каких условиях какой вариант предпочтителен? Есть ли вообще смысл заморачиваться и указывать список захвата вручную, может быть проще всегда писать `[&]` и не напрягать мозг, компилятор всё и так оптимизирует?

Comment: `[&]` - захват всех переменных по ссылке. `[=]` - по значению. Зависит сильно от ситуации, в частности от относительного времени жизни лямбды и захватываемых переменных. Ситуация схожа с вопросом - передавать аргументы в функцию по константой ссылке или по значению?

Comment: Если верить вот этой статье http://scrutator.me/post/2011/10/14/lamda-auto-decltype.aspx захватываются не все переменные, а только те, которые непосредственно используются в лямбде

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При захвате переменной по ссылке существует опасность что ссылка в итоге проживет дольше чем переменная, поэтому такого варианта надо избегать при работе с долгоживущими лямбдами.

Кроме того, при использовании варианта "захват всего по значению", он же `[=]` есть риск получить циклическую ссылку или еще какую-нибудь ерунду по невнимательности.

Поэтому для долгоживущих лямбд надо всегда явно указывать список захватываемых переменных:

```
auto lambda1 = [x](int a) { return a < x; };
```

С другой стороны, если время жизни лямбды не превышает одного оператора в вашем коде - то захват всего по ссылке не сделает ничего страшного.

Так, например, известно что `std::for_each` не сохраняет переданный ему функтор никуда:

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [&](int a) {
  if (a < x) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Захватывать, следуя Мейерсу, по умолчанию вообще не стоит: по ссылке - чревато висячими ссылками, по значению - висячими указателями (особенно в плане `this`).

Т.е. всегда используйте захват только того, что вам нужно, и так, как того требует код (что именно вы хотите достичь своей лямбдой).

Answer (score 0):

Единственная причина для захвата внешнего контекста целиком (да и то только по ссылке) - это инициализация при помощи лямбд (не помню, как этот подход называется), выглядит так:

```
QString labelPref = "label_";
widget->setLayout([&]{
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout.addWidget(new QLabel(labelPref + "1"));
    layout.addWidget(new QLabel(labelPref + "2"));
    return layout;
    }()
);
```

Тут висячую ссылку проблематично получить, но есть сомнения в целесообразности использования этого подхода.

Comment: Напишите без захвата что-то типа поиска `std::find_if` с лямбдой как предикат...

Comment: @Harry, я имел в виду контекст целиком, а не конкретные переменные, поправил текст.

Comment: А, тогда понятнее, что вы имели в виду.